# How do I read a users Tweets starting with the oldest?

Tags: twitter, sorting

I've just started to follow 'RealTimeWWII' but I'd like to read his Tweets to date starting with the first (he has ~850 so far so I think they should still be all there)

I keep clicking 'More' but eventually my shoddy wireless connection chokes. Is there a way to just reverse sort them?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that in Firefox by installing [Reverse Timeline](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/read-all-tweetsreverse-timelin/) addon.

> Reverse Timeline (former:Read All Tweets) 0.6.10.6:
>   Show unread tweets in reverse chronological order to read easily on
>   twitter. You can also apply this add-on to a list.

Comment: This seems to only work for new, unread Tweets, all existing Tweets are marked as read (which happens automatically it seems)

Comment: "This add-on has been removed by its author."  Which is a shame, because now twitter doesn't even show tweet replies in chronological order,   nor offer a simple button to re-sort.

Comment: I found the *github* page of the extension which may be useful: https://github.com/masahal/ReverseTimeline